# Inferrence for peaked likelihoods

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-error, asymptotics, laplace-distribution, hessian

Suppose I have the likelihood $f(X|\theta)$ of some rich model, where $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and I have been able to find its maximum, $\hat\theta$.

Suppose further that for some $i$, the plot of $\log f(X|\hat\theta_{-i};\theta_i)$ around $\theta_i=\hat\theta_i$ looks locally piecewise linear, with a point of non-differentiability at $\hat\theta_i$. (Indeed, if anything, the function is convex either side of the kink.)

Is there any (consistent) way to derive standard errors for $\hat\theta$? If the usual Normal limiting distribution comes from taking a second order Taylor approximation around the optimum, can one instead take an approximation including terms in $1[\theta>\hat\theta]$ and $1[\theta<\hat\theta]$ and then use some kind of generalized asymmetric Laplace limiting distribution?

Note: One possibility that always works is getting confidence intervals via inverting likelihood ratio tests. Unfortunately, in context this is computationally infeasible since re-estimating the model under parameter restrictions takes too long. Indeed, the dimension $n$ is high enough that even bootstrapping would be faster than inverting likelihood ratio tests. (Bootstrapping is also computationally infeasible here for the same reason.)